# Show all wp_query posts before query filter

Tags: wordpress, isset

I'm trying to figure out how to filter properly wp_query. The code which I have currently works fine, but the outcome is - it shows no posts at the beginning. Only after filtering. So the issue is with validating the select input. I've tried multiple ways to achieve that, yet without success.

This is my code

```
 $args_main_query = array(
        'post_type' => 'newoldcars',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
            'taxonomy' => 'cars',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $_POST["car_age"],
            ),
        ),

    );
$query = new WP_Query( $args_main_query );
```

how to do it properly??

Comment: When you say "Only after filtering" do you mean after form submission? When a user has selected car age.

Comment: exactly - so when I load the page, it shows only filtering form. When the user press submit button, posts appear. I want to have a quite different situation - the loop should load from the beginning, and when a user use filter form, it shows only specific posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is only add the filtering when its been chosen...

```
$args_main_query = array(
    'post_type'      => 'newoldcars',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1 
);
if( isset($_POST["car_age"]) ) {
    $args_main_query['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
           'taxonomy' => 'cars',
           'field'    => 'slug',
           'terms'    => $_POST["car_age"],
        )
    );
}
$query = new WP_Query( $args_main_query );
```

That way it only filters on car age when someone has selected a value.